# Two way binding with global variable

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a top-navbar that displays customer's {{name}}. But now I have another page/component somewhere in the application which can update the customer's information. Assume that I have updated a customer's name, how can 
I update my top-nav bar which is showing the customer's name?

The top-navbar is binded to the userInfo component and the other page is a another component. Now I am looking for something like a global variable which gets changed from any other component and gets reflected. So that I may bind customer's {{name}} with that global variable, and I will then update that variable from anywhere in the application.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: you can put all variable in a file and export them .

Comment: tried exporting but I can't update exported variables . I can only read from them but can't update the values of those exported variables.Where as I need to update them in order to see the change

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible, there are many approach to accomplish this functionality i am sharing one of them
we can achieve this thing with service 
Create service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  // Observable string sources
  private nameChangeSource = new Subject<string>(); 
  // Observable string streams
  nameChangedAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();

  announcedTheName(mission: string) {
    this.nameChangeSource .next(mission);
  }  
}
```

in navbar component inject this service and add subscribe like this

```
  constructor(private userService : UserService ) {
    userService.nameChangedAnnounced$.subscribe(
      name=> {
       console.log(name);
      });
  }
```

From page send the name like this

```
this.userService.announcedTheName(name);
```

Comment: and suppose, I have multiple things to announce like name, wallet amount etc . then I have to create wallet$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable(); ?

And what this approach is called? can you please share something regarding this technique so that I may have some knowlege about this appraoch?

Comment: yes you have to.. but you can pass object as well, this practice is  recommended by Angular so no doubt its best practice here ref link https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction please search the interaction with service in this page,, please accept this question.. give me more point

Comment: just one question. This thing( userService.nameChangedAnnounced$) once set is not going out even after logout from application.
I have even unsubscribe that but the value does not goes out until i hit f5 from browser

Comment: in navbar or where you subscribe nameChangedAnnounced add lifecycle event ngOnDestroy and call  unsubscribe  method